# Network theorem origin

Tags: circuit-theory

While finding the norton's equivalent curcuit,we 
1.find the short circuit current through the load
2.Find the resistance between the two points across which load is connected shorting the voltage sources or replacing them with internal resistance.
3.make an equivalent circuit with a current source of magnitude of the short circuit current with the load resistance in parallel.

BUT from where these rules come from?
How can we assure that following these steps we can replace a circuit with the equivalent one.

Comment: Mainly from the work of telegraphy engineers e.g. Léon Charles Thévenin (30 March 1857, Meaux, Seine-et-Marne – 21 September 1926, Paris) was a French telegraph engineer who extended Ohm's law to the analysis of complex electrical circuits.

Comment: @Jlm Dearden could you please illaborate?

Comment: Telegraphy engineers needed to find a practical way of testing and locating faults on (very long) lines - as they had no access to the whole circuit they took a **black box** approach - modelling the whole circuit as if it were contained in a 'black box' where they only had access to the output terminals.  It's all on google if you want to research it.

Answer (score 0):

The Norton theorem is a direct consequence of the superposition principle which arises from the linearity of the Maxwell's equations.

Suppose we have the following general network

[image]

where i=1,2,...,N , and j=1,2,...,M.

Hence we can express the current I as

$$I=\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i V_i+\sum_{j=1}^M \beta_i A_i + G_N V=A_N+G_N V,$$

which is the Norton theorem.